# How does two port numbers works at the same time?

Tags: http, networking, google-cloud-platform, port, gke-networking

Now i am getting super confused with how ports actually work ,
This is my understanding of ports. I know that port 80 is for HTTP protocol and port 443 is for HTTPS protocol, so whenever I access `http://website.com [(name or ip)]`, it is converted to `http://website.com:80 [(name or ip)]`,  and when I access `https://website.com [(name or ip)]`, it gets converted to `https://website.com:443 [(name or ip)]`.

So, if i am accessing a website on another port, i.e, i have my local setup of either springboot or angular app, and they are HTTP endpoints,
and I access `http://localhost:someportNumber` (example: `http://localhost:5000`), how does that get translated to port, as I have explicitly specified port 5000, but HTTP works on port 80.

Can you please help me with my understanding of how ports works.
Till now I was clear on how ports work, but now when I think of it like this today, it challenges my understanding of ports.

I came across this conflict of understanding when I was learning about the services on Google Kubernetes Engine. In there I created a service of type nodeport, which had configs like

```
port: 443
targetPort: 443
nodePort: 31000
```

and when I accessed external ip address of one of the nodes `https://[external-ip]:31000`, it worked.

So I began to challenge my understanding and I can't wrap this around my head that how is it working.

PS:- It is not about the concept of NodePort/ClusterIP/LoadBalancer. But in general about how these ports work with protocol port http or https, with a port of application.

Comment: HTTP works on port 80 *by default*, which is only to say that if you don't specify a port you get 80. Similarly for 443. If you specify something else, and there is an HTTP or HTTPS service listening at that other port, it will also work. No mystery.

Comment: To add to the answers below, port 80 does not need to speak HTTP, that is just a convention as in the norm. The service listening on port 80 or 443 could speak any protocol it wants. The combination of IP Address and TCP Port just creates a connection address, like a phone call. In the security world, we often run other protocols on ports either to mask (hide) or confuse the other side. An example that is fairly common is running SSH on port 80/443. The listener speaks both HTTP(S) and SSH and behaves accordingly.

Comment: Now you might ask where port 80 comes from when you specify `http`. The Internet RFCs specify common port numbers and reserved port numbers. In the TCP protocol stack is a directory that translates HTTP -> the number 80. This directory is usually a file built into the operating system. There are APIs that your program can call to look up what port number `HTTP` translates to.

Comment: and someone gave a star to this question?

Comment: @suren, some details are confusing to newbies. Following the answers helps me explain them better. I volunteer teaching teens cloud computing at my church, so I see all kinds of questions. Some are so basic I have a hard time explaining in simple English without all the techno babble.

Comment: @suren - I did as well. I knew the answer to this question, but I felt there might be some insightful answers or comments here that would add depth to my understanding.

Comment: @suren - Also, the star means "Favorite," which often people use like a bookmark (even if it's not the UX intent). Not like an award. Maybe you view that differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify any port (such as 5000 in your example).  The URI simply begins with `http` to indicate what *protocol* is used - it does not mandate the use of port 80.  The *address* is then used to contact the host on the specified port (which will be port 80 unless a different port was specified).  Upon successful connection, the client then expects the server to speak HTTP.

On the server side, there is just a program that is listening on a port, waiting for incoming connections.

Answer (score 3):

In the old days, one wouldn't call a person at a company directly.  Instead one would call the main company switchboard and ask for the person at some extension.

Operator: How can I help you?
You: Extension 123
Operator: Connecting you now

Think of a "port" like an extension at a company.  The hostname/IP address is the phone number of the company, the port is the extension at that company.

Going back to the analogy, once you are connected to the phone extension, you have a conversation.  Both parties have an expectation of the conversation to be had.  For example, if I call the extension corresponding to sales, I can place an order while if I call the extension corresponding to recruitment, I can submit my resume.  This relationship between the purpose of the call and the extension is by convention and is not implicit in the extension itself.

When you form a connection over the internet to some machine at port 80, the assumption is that we will be exchanging HTTP traffic.  However if I form a connection to some machine at port 5000, then there is nothing to prevent THAT connection from also sending and receiving HTTP traffic.  For example, if sales at my company can be contacted on extension 80 and you can place an order there may also be an additional extension (5000) which you can call to place other types of orders that aren't available at the 80 extension.

See also:

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/tcpip-ports-sockets/